# c# Extract multiple numbers from a string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract whole numbers of different length from a string with lots of formatting. The string in question could look like this:

```
string s = "Hallo (221122321 434334 more text3434 even mor,34343 343421.343sf 343";
```

The output I'm looking for is an array of:

```
{221122321,434334,3434,34343,343421,343,343}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var result = new Regex(@"\d+").Matches(s)
                              .Cast<Match>()
                              .Select(m => Int32.Parse(m.Value))
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Excellent solution, but I'd change `.OfType<Match>` to `.Cast<Match>` to better indicate that I expect all the match items to actually be of type `Match` (they cannot be any other type).

Comment: Wouldn't you want to change `m => m.Value` to `m => Int32.Parse(m.Value)` so you have an array of int, instead of an array of string?  (There are no quotes in the desired output.)

Comment: Very Elegant Solutions, now even better after the update !

Answer (score -1):

Use a foreach loop like this:

```
string result = "";

foreach (string str in s)
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(str, out number))
       result += s;
    else
       result += ",";
}
```

Comment: This will not work, also will not result in a array.